# Quickest way to update SQLite database on android (or add record if it does not yet exist)

Tags: android, sqlite, optimization, android-sqlite

I have written the following code to update some information in a database using SQLite. The idea is to update a value (userAverageTime) in case the entry already exist, or make a new record if the entry does not yet exist.

Here is the code:

```
    public void updateTableLevelsAverageTime(DatabaseOperations dop, LinkedList<Level> levels) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = KEY_NUMBERS + " = ?";
    for (Level level: levels) {
        String[] args = {level.toString()};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_AVERAGE_TIME, level.getAverageTime());
        int result = SQ.update(TABLE_LEVELS, cv, selection, args);
        if (result == 0) {
            //If the entry doesn't exist, it must be a new level... thus add it with 0 as userseconds
            ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
            cv2.put(KEY_NUMBERS, level.toString());
            cv2.put(KEY_AVERAGE_TIME, level.getAverageTime());
            cv2.put(KEY_USER_TIME, 0);
            SQ.insert(TABLE_LEVELS, null, cv2);
            Log.d("Database operations", "Row added");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Database operations", "Row updated");
        }
    }
    SQ.close();
}
```

(KEY_*** are column names that are defined elsewhere in the code)

I was wondering if this was the best approach, though. The code takes quite some time to run.

I have read somewhere that if you want to update data you can do this batch-wise. But can you do this as well when you want to update only if a record exists and when you want to add the record if it doesn't exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `REPLACE INTO` command as you would use an `INSERT INTO` one, in order not to have to check if the record exists and execute the corresponding `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO` command.
SQLite will first delete the row (if existing) and then insert it newly.

Therefore you can write an `execSQL()` instruction which uses the `REPLACE INTO` command where you are currently executing a query and then deciding which command to execute next.

The `REPLACE INTO` will help you skipping all that logic.
I find it really useful.